# How can i make querys to arrays in a postgres db using sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

i have model like this:

```
sequelize.define("user", {
    name: {
      type:Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
    favoriteColor: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      defaultValue: 'green'
    },
    age: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    cash: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    tag: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    }
```

which i have insisted into successfully but i'm having issue on
query to findAll where tag contains ... for example
findAll where tag contains black

[querys to arrays in a postgres db using sequelize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJqYY.png)

Comment: Hi Damilare, Thanks for your question.
1. Did you check if the data comming from request.body has receiving any value?. Maybe you can log it or debugged it to validate it.
2. Can you please share more info about, relation between tag an user in case re existed, express router or the router for the request endpoint. To have more idea

Comment: Yes thanks for replying, for the first question i do check the data coming form request.body and of couse it as value, and for that of your second question tag is a column in the user with the datatype of array[] (Since  my database is postgresql i try to take make use of the datatype array which  is avaliable for postgresql only in sequelize) yes i have successfully insisted into db ( which looks like this in the db: {red,234,black}) and now my question is now to query to findaAll base on the request.body (for example trying to find all user which as a tag of black) thanks

Comment: here is what having being try: tag: async (req, res) => {
        const data = req.body;
         console.log(data)
        const array_tag = await User.findAll({
            where: {
                tag: {
                    [Op.contained]: [data]
                }
            }
        });
        if(array_tag === null){
            //! if array_tag is null
            res.send({
                message:'ERROR' 
            });
        }else{
            //todo if there is no error
            res.send(array_tag);
        }
    }

Comment: hello boykland,

Comment: Hi Damilare, I think we can do a one o one call, so we can share screen and reach to a solution. https://calendly.com/boykland/boyk-dojo please fill the appointment

Comment: okay thanks .. ill be experting you in the meeting

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Op for that.

`array: { [Op.contains]: ["black"] }`

In order to use it you will need to import it.

`const { Op } = require('sequelize');`

Comment: thanks but it isn't working

Comment: I know it might be late but I think this is a more appropriate solution

Comment: in your case array is tag.

Comment: still not getting the result